# DataGrid.Items.Count doesn't work as per expectation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF `DataGrid` named `datagrid1` and I want to check if `DataGrid` rows are not empty.

Then how could I achieve this. I tried this but failed.

```
if (dataGrid1.Items.Count != 0)
{
      //submit
}
else
{
      MessageBox.Show("Data Grid is empty");
}
```

Comment: What does it mean it failed? What is the error you get? Please provide [mcve]

Comment: fails means that even my datagrid is empty it executes if block

Comment: fails means that even my datagrid is empty it executes if block, but i want that if datagrid is epmty it should go to else block.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set [`CanUserAddRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows(v=vs.110).aspx) false:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" CanUserAddRows="false"></DataGrid>
```

You get an empty row at the bottom of your `DataGrid` usually. This is why, you don't go to the else part, even though your `DataGrid` is empty.

Comment: what would be effect of CanUserAddRows="false"  ??

Comment: @JahanzaibNiazi Just try it and you will see the result. You get an empty row at the bottom of your DataGrid usually. This is why, you don't go to the else part, even your `DataGrid` is empty.